# Remove all matches containing a string until its next space

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to delete all matches in a text following this pattern:

- Each match starts with linux-
- Each match ends with a space
- (Remove linux-* until immediate next space)

EXAMPLE:
From this text:

> ibudev1 libudev1 libweather-ion7 libxatracker2 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers milou

Get this:

> ibudev1 libudev1 libweather-ion7 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers milou

It is to be run on Ubuntu, so Bash environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/linux-[^ ]* //g'
```

`[^ ]*` matches all following characters that are not space and `*` following that means one or more

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lpe 's/(?!<\S)linux-\S*(\s+|$)//g'
```

would do it. That's `linux-` provided it's not preceded by a non-whitespace (`(?!<\S)`) followed by any number of non-whitespaces (`\S*`) followed by one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) or the end of the line to be replaced with nothing.

The `(?!<\S)` negative look-behind check is to avoid matching on the `linux-` found within a package name like in `g++-i586-linux-gnu`, `util-linux-dbgsym`...

Note that we remove the whitespace *after* but not before the package name. That means that if the last word on the line is a `linux-*` one, there will be trailing whitespace left afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '%s' "$list" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v '^linux-' | paste -sd " "
```